# I cant connect to a Windows FTP server with Microsoft Windows CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, ftp

I have been trying for 2 days to connect to a FTP server ( on Microsoft Windows 2016) through windows command prompt, but have been unsuccessful.

I can use any other FTP client (filezilla for example), but CMD (which was required due to the software that was leaning on it) just couldn't connect.

I had been using a long password (35 characters). However, it turns out that CMD can only transmit passwords up to a certain length. My 31 character password was too long, and it turns out that a 8 character password was much more appropriate.

**Don't use long passwords in CMD if connecting to a FTP server.** More detail on the matter would be appreciated if it's available.

Answer (score 1):

Windows CMD is limited in the length of password it can transmit for a FTP server. Use a short password if connecting to a FTP server with CMD.